# pipeline error in pyspark when excuting below code

Tags: pyspark

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark import SQLContext
 sqc=SQLContext(sc)
 input=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/uber.txt")
 df=input.map(lambda x:x.split(","))
 df=sqc.createDataFrame(input.map(lambda x:x.split(","))
 input.map(lambda r:Row(basedid=r[0],dt=r[1],nveh=int(r[2]),ncus=int(r[3])))))
```

when I executed above code,I got following error.

> TypeError: 'PipelinedRDD' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

Last line of your code should be

```
input.map(lambda r: r.split(",")).map(lambda r:Row(basedid=r[0],dt=r[1],nveh=int(r[2]),ncus=int(r[3])))
```

and remove extra parentheses at the end of last line.